# How to forward Display of remote server in bluehost to local machine

Tags: python, ssh, display, bluehost

I am running a python script on a Bluehost remote machine, and my script opens a browser window to ask the user for his permission to access his personal calendar. This is part of the oAuth2 protocol. In fact, this is for me to give access to this script to access my Google Calendar. I am running this script through SSH from my local machine, and need it to display on my local machine. Is there a way to do this? Has someone with a Bluehost account done this?

thanks

Comment: What you need is called X forwarding https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely

Comment: Alternatively, I don't think I've ever used an oauth script that opened a web browser. You typically have some login token to access the api

Comment: change script to display url and then you can open browser manually on local computer. After that you can copy you could get token which you can use in script - but it also needs changes in script.

Comment: @furas do you have example code to do this with the python webbrowser.open method? This method is passed a URL to open, but the problem as I said is that it wants to open the webbrowser in the remote machine , since the script is running on the remote machine?

Comment: don't use `webbrowser.open()` to open it - script has to display `url` on screen and then you can copy/paste to browser on local computer to run it. After that you may get screen with token which you would have to put in script - so it needs some changes in script. And it may need to change setting in Google when application was registered - and use url `localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1`